# use GwtCreateResource to provide text programatically

Tags: gwt, resources, uibinder, gwtp, clientbundle

I would like my uiBinder to use a ClientBundle which will provide some runtime customized labels. Kind of a TextResource but not from a text file !
I tried with GwtCreateResource but from the [DevGuide](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#GwtCreateResource) it seems like it's not possible. Am I right ? (create() and name() are the only methods available) 
What I would like to achieve is something like this:

client bundle:

```
public interface MyWidgetResources extends ClientBundle {
    GwtCreateResource<WidgetLabels> labels();

    @Source("lol.css")
    CssResource style();
}
```

labels class:

```
public final class MyWidgetLabels {
    public String title() {
        return load("mywidget-title");
    }

    public String banner() {
        return load("mywidget-banner");
    }

    private String load(String key) {
        // load from external..
    }
}
```

uiBinder:

```
<ui:with type="com.package.MyWidgetResources" field="res"/>

<gwt:SimplePanel>
    <gwt:Label text="{res.labels.title}"></gwt:Label>
    <gwt:Label text="{res.labels.banner}"></gwt:Label>
</gwt:SimplePanel>
```

My code looks like this already but `res.label.title` does not work because GwtCreateResource can only serve as class instantiator (`res.labels.create().title()`).

Is there a solution for me ? Maybe with a custom [ResourceGenerator](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Pluggable_Resource_Generation) ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as `MyWidgetLabels` can be created by GWT.create, you can put anything you want into that type, and you can make it behave however you'd like. You will need the `create` reference in your uibinder as you suggested at the end of the post to actually build the object, so your lines will look about like this:

```
<gwt:Label text="{res.labels.create.title}"></gwt:Label>
```

Each `.` separated piece (except the first, which is a ui:field/@UiField) is a no-arg method to be called - you declared `labels()` in `MyWidgetResources`, `create()` already existed in `GwtCreateResource`, and you created `title()` in your own `MyWidgetLabels` type.

Since that first piece is a ui:field/@UiField, you could have another that references `res.labels.create` as something like `labels` so that later you could instead say:

```
<gwt:Label text="{labels.title}"></gwt:Label>
```

Finally, yes, you could build your own ResourceGenerator which would enable you to do whatever you wanted to emit the type in question, as long as you extended the `ResourcePrototype` type and had a `getName()` method.

Comment: well `res.labels.create.title`actually doesn't work. i can't access any methods of labels. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: No, I'll try a sample like this shortly. I do use exactly this way of referring to nested properties in a CssResource, and in a uibinder to *reference* a cssresource, so I'm surprised to hear that it isn't working.